# Spark Multidimensional RDD partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

If I create two rdds like these:

```
a = sc.parallelize([[1 for j in range(3)] for i in xrange(10**9)])

b = sc.parallelize([[1 for j in xrange(10**9)] for i in range(3)])
```

When you think about it partitioning first one is intuitive, billion rows are partitioned around workers.
But for the second one there are 3 rows and for each row there are billion item.

My question is: For the second line, if I have 2 workers does one row goes to one worker, and the other two rows goes to the other worker?

Answer (score 2):

Data distribution in Spark is limited to the top level sequence you use to create a RDD.

Depending on a configuration in the second case you'll get at most three non-empty partitions, each assigned to a single worker so in the second scenario 1-2 split is a likely outcome.

Generally speaking small number of elements, especially very large, doesn't fit well into Spark processing model.

Comment: Does this mean, if I have 10 workers, the data would be partitioned only 3 workers?(In the case of second line)

Comment: Thats right. No matter how much workers you have most of them will be idle. Moreover each element has to fit into a worker memory.

Comment: Thanks. That would really help.